# Downloading pictures with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm starting with scrapy, and I have first real problem. It's downloading pictures. So this is my spider.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from example.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url

import re

class ProductSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "product"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = [
            "http://www.domain.com/category/supplies/accessories.do"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        sites = hxs.select('//td[@class="thumbtext"]')
        number = 0
        for site in sites:
            item = ProductItem()
            xpath = '//div[@class="thumb"]/img/@src'
            item['image_urls'] = site.select(xpath).extract()[number]
            item['image_urls'] = 'http://www.domain.com' + item['image_urls']
            items.append(item)
            number = number + 1
        return items
```

When I quote `ITEM_PIPELINES` and `IMAGES_STORE` in `settings.py` this way I get the proper URL for picture I want to download (copy pasted it into browser for check).

But when I unquote those i get following error:

```
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url')
exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:h
```

and I can't download my pictures.

I've searched for the whole day and didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: do you have a pipeline to process the urls? did you register your pipeline in settings.py? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html, is great reference.  do you have the proper permissions to write to the IMAGE_STORE path?

Comment: yes I did everything as it is said, actually I used that reference but still...no

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the image URL you scraped is relative. To construct the absolute URL use [urlparse.urljoin](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    image_relative_url = hxs.select("...").extract()[0]
    import urlparse
    image_absolute_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, image_relative_url.strip())
    item['image_urls'] = [image_absolute_url]
    ...
```

---

Haven't used ITEM_PIPELINES, but the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#using-the-images-pipeline) say:

> In a Spider, you scrape an item and put the URLs of its images into a image_urls field.

So, item['image_urls'] should be a list of image URLs. But your code has:

```
item['image_urls'] = 'http://www.domain.com' + item['image_urls']
```

So, i guess it iterates your single URL char by char - using each as URL.

Comment: This didn't help. As I said I already have absolute path my way, I tested url I get and it was indeed the url of an image. I tried this and result is same like before, I get good url but when I turn on ITEM_PIPELINES and IMAGES_STORE i get the same error as before

Comment: but this way of getting absolute url is definitely better, so thanks for that

Comment: @iblazevic, see my update. And don't forget to upvote/accept answers

Comment: edit file in the scrapy sources: `scrapy/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py`, method `ImagesPipeline.get_media_requests`. Put there `print item.get('image_urls', [])`

Comment: you can even add a print right before where the exception is raised, to see _what_ url is invalid. > it's getting so frustrating < this is how you get experience :)

Comment: I don't think `u` is the problem. But why Error processing `{'image_urls': u'http ://www.reallygoodstuff.com/images/set_a/en_us/local/products/thumb/159361.jpg'}` and not `Error processing u'http ://www.reallygoodstuff.com/images/set_a/en_us/local/products/thumb/159361.jpg`? Isn't the item['image_urls] in your case a list of dicts? I think you still must check if item['iamge_urls'] is a list of urls.

Comment: Upvoted, since this answer deserves some regonition since the question asker basically used your answer to solve their issue

Answer (score 7):

I think that you may need to provide your image url in a list to the Item:

```
item['image_urls'] = [ 'http://www.domain.com' + item['image_urls'] ]
```

Comment: That is correct. Even if your URL is correct, image_urls is supposed to be a list of urls, no a string.

Comment: yeah, it's supposed to be a list. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Smarter approach @sir alecxe.