# scrapy error :exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

Tags: python, scrapy

I use `try except` to avoid error,but My terminal still show error but not the log message :

```
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:
```

How can I avoid this error when scrapy didn't get image_urls?
Please guide me ,thank you very much.

```
    try:

        item['image_urls'] = ["".join(image.extract()) ]     
    except:
        log.msg("no image foung!. url={}".format(response.url),level=log.INFO)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the `image_urls` field should be a list, not a str.

```
item['image_urls'] = image.extract()
```

If you do so, and still raise the exception, it seems that the urls you scraped is the relative path.

the `ImagePipeline` doesn't know your host, so it can not generate the absolute path to crawl.

```
import urlparse
item['image_urls'] = [ urlparse.urljoin(response.url, u) for u in image.extract() ]
```

Comment: in python 3.6 it's `from  urllib.parse import urljoin` and `...[urljoin(...`

Answer (score 10):

"Missing scheme in request url" means that you are missing the "http://" part of the url, most probably because your URL's are relative and should be absolute.