# Scrapy download files from FTP

Tags: python-2.7, file, download, ftp, scrapy

I need to download a group of csv using scrapy from FTP. But first I need to scrape a website(https://www.douglas.co.us/assessor/data-downloads/) in order to get  the urls of csv in the ftp.I read about how to download files in the documentation([Downloading and processing files and images](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html))

**settings**

```
custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1, 


        },
        'FILES_STORE' : os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    }
```

**parse**

```
def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("In parse method!!!")
        # Property Ownership        
        property_ownership = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Ownership')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Location
        property_location = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Location')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Improvements
        property_improvements = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Improvements')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Value
        property_value = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Value')]/@href").extract_first()

        item = FiledownloadItem()
        self.insert_keyvalue(item,"file_urls",[property_ownership, property_location, property_improvements, property_value])

        yield item
```

But I got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py",
>   line 653, in _runCallbacks
>       current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py",
>   line 79, in process_item
>       requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py",
>   line 382, in get_media_requests
>       return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.files_urls_field, [])]   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in **init**
>       self._set_url(url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py",
>   line 58, in _set_url
>       raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: [

The best explanation to my problem is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521064/2399444)  of this question [scrapy error :exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516339/scrapy-error-exceptions-valueerror-missing-scheme-in-request-url), that explain that the problem is that urls to download are missing the "http://".

What should I do in my case? Can I use FilesPipeline? or I need to do something different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
>   ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: [

According to the traceback, scrapy thinks your file url is '['.
My best guess is that you have an error in the `insert_keyvalue()` method.
Also, why have a method for this? Simple assignment should work.

Comment: that's exactly my problem, thanks a lot,I thought my problem was another. The simple assignment should work you are work, but I usually use this method because for other items I need to verify if the results are None.