# Raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: javascript:void(0);

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my spider code

spider.py

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'moneycontrol'
    # allowed_domains = ['moneycontrol.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/']

    def parse(self, response):
        stoke_link_list = response.css("table a::attr(href)").getall()

        if response.css("span.span_price_wrap::text").getall(): # value of this variable only present in first run
            stock_name =  response.css("h1.pcstname::text").get()
            bse_price, nse_price = response.css("span.span_price_wrap::text").getall()
            print(stock_name + ' ' + bse_price + ' ' + nse_price)
        else:
            print('stock_name bse_price nse_price')

        for link in stoke_link_list:
            if link is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(link)
                # yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

while running this I am getting a strange error. It give error while scraping some website while running that again it gives error while **scraping** different website (I mean may run for previous website).

Error:

```
2020-08-20 19:52:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/motilal-oswal-midcap-30-fund-regular-plan/MMO025> (referer: https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/pharmaceuticals/abbottindia/AI51)
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/moneycontrol/moneycontrol/spiders/my_spider.py", line 24, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 69, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: javascript:void(0);
```

Run2

```
2020-08-20 19:55:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/dsp-equity-opportunities-fund-regular-plan/MDS011> (referer: https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/pharmaceuticals/alkemlaboratories/AL05)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/moneycontrol/moneycontrol/spiders/my_spider.py", line 24, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/home/vishvajeet/Desktop/Programming/python/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 69, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: javascript:void(0);
```

I looked other stackoverflow answers but none of them is solving my issue. like trying `start_urls` to list, using follow etc.
[Missing scheme in request URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103533/missing-scheme-in-request-url)

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: @Gallaecio please describe more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error '**Missing scheme in request url**' means that the URL does not have the http:// or https:// prefix.

The problem is happening due to the presence of links with relative URLs in the webpage being tested.

For example, the link named '***Zee entertain***' on the ***moneycontrol.com*** website has the

href value of "/india/stockpricequote/mediaentertainment/zeeentertainmententerprises/ZEE"

So, when the Python program is trying to open this link, the 'Missing scheme' error is being thrown.

---

**How to fix the problem?**

The problem of '**missing scheme**' can be fixed by prepending
**https://hostname** to all relative URL links (I.E., the links that do not begin with http:// or https://)

**Code snippet to prepend https://hostname to relative URLs:**

```
for link in stoke_link_list:
    if link is not None:
        if not link.startswith("https://moneycontrol.com/")
            page_url = ("https://moneycontrol.com/" + link)
```