# Scrapy yield using the dict, not the value

Tags: python, scrapy

i want to pass the link returned in the response.css to items and then use this value to download my file.  But everytime that I yield the dict I recive the following error:
`ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h`

My code is:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from diarioOficial.items import DiariooficialItem

class Crawl_Diario(scrapy.Spider):
    TERRITORY_ID = '12'
    name = 'do_acre'
    allowed_domains = ['www.diario.ac.gov.br/']

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.diario.ac.gov.br/'
    ]
def parse(self, response):
        yield DiariooficialItem(
            file_urls = response.css("div.edhoje a").attrib['href']
        )
```

How can I fix that error?

My items.py is:

````
class DiariooficialItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing scheme in request URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103533/missing-scheme-in-request-url)

Comment: Unfortunately not. In this case, he just forgotten to use start_urls as a list. In my case, I believe middlewares is using all dict value to make the request, returning that error

Comment: On a side note - not sure how it could produce the error you're seeing, but I'd 1) drop the trailing slash from your allowed domains and 2) change your selector or be `response.css("div.edhoje a::attr(href)").getall()`.

Comment: @JonClements adding ```.getall()``` fix the problem. I believe it expect a list

Comment: Use `file_urls = [response.urljoin(response.css("div.edhoje a").attrib['href'])]`