# Extracting Images in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've read through a few other answers here but I'm missing something fundamental.  I'm trying to extract the images from a website with a CrawlSpider.

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'healthycomm'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['healthycomm.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'healthycomm.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '~/Desktop/scrapy_nsml/healthycomm/images'
```

items.py

```
class HealthycommItem(scrapy.Item):
    page_heading = scrapy.Field()
    page_title = scrapy.Field()
    page_link = scrapy.Field()
    page_content = scrapy.Field()
    page_content_block = scrapy.Field()

    image_url = scrapy.Field()
    image = scrapy.Field()
```

HealthycommSpider.py

```
class HealthycommSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "healthycomm_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["healthycommunity.org.au"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.healthycommunity.org.au/',
    )
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_items", follow=False), ) 


    def parse_items(self, response):
        content = Selector(response=response).xpath('//body')
        for nodes in content:

            img_urls = nodes.xpath('//img/@src').extract()

            item = HealthycommItem()
            item['page_heading'] = nodes.xpath("//title").extract()
            item["page_title"] = nodes.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
            item["page_link"] = response.url
            item["page_content"] = nodes.xpath('//div[@class="CategoryDescription"]').extract()
            item['image_url'] = img_urls 
            item['image'] = ['http://www.healthycommunity.org.au' + img for img in img_urls]

            yield item
```

I'm not very familiar with Python in general, but I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: i think u missed a '/' while appending to the image . i think it should be http://www.healthycommunity.org.au/

Comment: The relative path is being returned, ie:
/path/path2/image.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773732/downloading-pictures-with-scrapy check this

Comment: Turns out I was missing an "s" in the items class - image_urls instead of image_url.  How frustrating

Comment: so did ur problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the standard `ImagesPipeline`, you need to change your `parse_items` method to something like:

```
import urlparse
...

    def parse_items(self, response):
        content = Selector(response=response).xpath('//body')
        for nodes in content:

            # build absolute URLs
            img_urls = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, src)
                        for src in nodes.xpath('//img/@src').extract()]

            item = HealthycommItem()
            item['page_heading'] = nodes.xpath("//title").extract()
            item["page_title"] = nodes.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
            item["page_link"] = response.url
            item["page_content"] = nodes.xpath('//div[@class="CategoryDescription"]').extract()

            # use "image_urls" instead of "image_url"
            item['image_urls'] = img_urls 

            yield item
```

And your item definition needs "`images`" and "`image_urls`" fields (plural, not singular)

The other way is to set `IMAGES_URLS_FIELD` and `IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD` to fit your item definition

Comment: Does `urlparse.urljoin(response.url, src)` respect a potential [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) for a document?

Comment: @SimonShine, I don't think so, but the new(er) [`response.urljoin(src)`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) does. See [the implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/response/text.py#L82).