# Regular Expression to find Images in various formats/tags

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need a regular expression which finds images within a websites source code. I have this so far:

```
images = re.findall(r'src=[\"|\']([^\"|\']+)[\"|\']',webpage.decode())
images.sort()
print (f'[+] {len(images)} images Found:')
for image in images:
    print(image)
```

This has been finding images in  the format:

`<img src="2001-a-space-odyssey.JPG"/>`

`<img src="http://www.example.com/content/icon.gif"/>`

but doesn't find images that are in the format:

`<form action="example.jpg">`

`<!-- <img src="big.jpg" /> -->`

`background-image:url("xine.png");`

I need a regular expression to find all of these, however, I don't want one that is like `png|jpeg|gif` etc..

Comment: this is because in your source code you are using `r'src=` so only the part after `src` gets searched for

Comment: why don't you want one like `png|jpeg|gif`? also what is the input?

Comment: Use a html tool to read it, a regexp is not the correct answer

Comment: @depperm If you could come up with a solution that includes `png|jpeg|gif` then id give it a shot, but ideally i would want it to find as many image extensions as possible without listing them all in the regex. The input is a url.

Comment: can you share what is in `webpage.decode()` as trying to make a regex to fit all the cases without knowing the input is basically luck. Also like @Ôrel I wouldn't recommend regex as a first choice but use an html tool

Comment: @JDoe  : Please see the answer below , and check if it works well, unless you have a very wierd fomat of the image , for Image file formats go throught the link and include it in your regex , I don't think there should any other escape route .

Comment: @JDoe: If you want to actually download those images, use Scrapy. There's a (slightly outdated) example here: [Extracting Images in Scrapy
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523841/extracting-images-in-scrapy) (StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not so much bothered about the image formats , then the below expression should do your job well :

```
pattern = "[\"|\'].*\.(?i:jpg|gif|png|bmp)[\"|\']"
images = re.findall(pattern,webpage.decode())
```

**?i , here i will ignore the case .**

**Edit** :

```
pattern : "[\=,\(][\"|\'].[^\=\"]+\.(?i:jpg|gif|png|bmp)[\"|\']"
```

Note : Removing the first two characters and last one characters from the match should give the required output

for various image formats you can check here : [Image file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#Stereo_formats)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your solution is alot closer to what im wanting however its displaying some of them like `"5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e" height="200" src="subfolder/The%20Martian%20-%20image.jpg"` and `"msc_asdf_logo.jpeg" height="100"/><img src="gchq-certified.jpg"`

Comment: @JDoe : I have added an edit to the answer and verified it as well , I have assumed that either  '=' or '(' will be there before start of any image name , and removing the first two characters and last one characters should give you the required answer , Please let me know if it doesn't works out

Comment: Works perfect so iv marked your answer correct!, one quick question if you have time. Its displaying them like `("xine.png"`
`="2001-a-space-odyssey.JPG"` how would i remove the `=,",(`?

Comment: @JDoe It's straight forward simple , as all the found strings will have either '=" or '("'  in the beginning , and double quotes(") at the end , so  <yourtext>[2:-1] , will trim first 2 characters and last one characters

Comment: @JDoe: It hardly works perfect: It allows for mismatching quotes, so it won't allow for images with quotes in them, it requires quotes, so it won't find `src=foo.jpg`, it doesn't match images without known filename extensions (which you specifically didn't want), it jumbles the cases of HTML attribute and CSS property, and it includes characters in the result that are not part of the filename, which you could avoid if you used [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Also, *it uses regex*. **Use an HTML parser.** :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Ôrel pointed out, this really isn't a job for regular expressions. In this answer I will try to get quite close to an acceptable answer, but I will refrain from heroic efforts when it shows that regex is not the right tool for the job, but solve as much as I think can be done reasonably with regex.

Taking [arbitrary](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1) [whitespace](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33) into account (e.g. `< i m g s r c = "foo.jpg" >`) explodes the pattern; you could handle this with a preprocessor (converting a whitespace-insensitive regular expression into one where optional whitespace is added at all possible positions). *(Heroic.)*

You specifically don't want to match `src="foo'`, since single quotes can contain double quotes and vice versa (e.g. `src="'hello'.jpg"`). Here you can use a capturing group (`(...)`) and a back-reference (`\1`):

```
>>> s = "src='hello', src=\"world\", src='foo\"bar\"', src=\"'quotes'suck\""
>>> [ src[1] for src in re.findall(r'src=(["\'])(.*?)\1', s) ]
['hello', 'world', 'foo"bar"', "'quotes'suck"]
```

This won't work when attributes are (incorrectly) missing quotes, like `src=foo.jpg`. You could extend the pattern slightly. Since there are now two (mutually exclusive) capturing groups, I'll use either of what they captured with `src[1] or src[2]`:

```
>>> s = "<img src='foo.jpg'>, <img src=baz.gif>, <img src=\"bar.png\">"
>>> [ src[1] or src[2] for src in re.findall(r'src=(["\'])(.*?)\1|src=([^\s>\'"]+)', s) ]
['foo.jpg', 'baz.gif', 'bar.png']
```

`src="..."` attributes might not belong to `<img>` tags (they might, for example, belong to `<script>` tags). You could match against the tag as well, but besides arbitrary whitespace, you have to take into account an arbitrary amount of preceding attributes before the `src="..."` attribute (e.g. `<img alt="wat" src="wat.png">`), and that's *just* image tags. *(Heroic.)*

You could instead use [cssselect](https://cssselect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for extracting `<img src="...">` tags:

```
from cssselect import GenericTranslator
from lxml.etree import fromstring

selector = GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath('img')
document = fromstring(...)
urls = [ e.get('src') for e in document.xpath(selector) ]
```

This is robust against the many possible formattings of HTML, the ordering of attributes, and so on. In case of [tag soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), lxml is [pretty robust](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

You could also try your luck with [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). See: [Extracting Images in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523841/extracting-images-in-scrapy) (StackOverflow)

Another thing you have to keep in mind is the [`<base>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) tag when images are located on relative addresses. A scraping framework or [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) will have that under control.

I'll address the three other cases separately:

1. If you want to consider `<form action="some.gif">` a reference to an image, and you don't want to filter based on trivial filename extensions, you can only really know by fetching the URL and matching the `Content-Type` header against `image/*`, because most likely the result of a form request is not directly an image. Here an HTML parser with CSS selectors will be equally useful, but I don't know if you can safely assume that forms will give you the right Content-Type if its form fields are not correctly filled out, so that presents another non-trivial problem.
2. Since image tags inside HTML comments like `<!-- <img src="big.jpg" /> -->` aren't part of the DOM, using an HTML parser won't help you here. But since the nice solution is no good here, using a regular expression might at least catch some trivial cases. Alternatively you could search and replace all cases of `<!--` and `-->` to re-include stuff into the DOM just so it can be extracted with an HTML parser, but you might risk breaking a well-formed HTML document that way. Still, you might risk that any HTML document is broken from the start.
3. If you want to also include CSS-sourced images like `background-image: url(xine.png)`, you're in equally deep when it comes to regular expressions: Neither HTML nor CSS are regular languages. I'm not sure which scrapers let you traverse all of a website's styling, but my guess is that you need to extract both `<style>` sections, externally sourced stylesheets and `style="..."` tags and traverse those chunks with a CSS parser like [tinycss](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

   Remember that the `<base>` tag applies for both internally and externally loaded stylesheets.

   Still, if you want to extract `url(...)`s from CSS, consider this:

   ```
   >>> s = 'p { background: url("../hello.gif"), url(\'http://example.com/rawr\'), url(meh.png); }'
   >>> [ url[1] for url in re.findall(r'url\((["\']?)(.*?)\1\)', s) ]
   ['../hello.gif', 'http://example.com/rawr', 'meh.png']
   ```

   This doesn't take arbitrary whitespace into consideration either.

At this point you haven't addressed images that are loaded in various ways at run-time. You could run a [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) and visit a website and extract images from its cache, but then you can't be sure that [CSS media queries](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) exclude you from getting e.g. high-resolution background images or mobile-specific icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `regex` to get all images :

```
data = '''<form action="example.jpg">
<!-- <img src="big.jpg" /> -->
background-image:url("xine.png");
<img src="2001-a-space-odyssey.JPG"/>
<img src="http://www.example.com/content/icon.gif"/>
'''

>>> re.findall("([-\w]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg))", data, re.IGNORECASE)

['example.jpg', 'big.jpg', 'xine.png', '2001-a-space-odyssey.JPG', 'icon.gif']
```

Comment: didn't dv but looking at the testwebsite there is an image `<img src="https://resizing.flixster.com/qYv4_Lxypr9srpkW4qALgQM9o_g=/fit-in/1152x864/v1.aDsxMzE0MDY7ajsxNzUwNjsxMjAwOzQwOTY7MTc0NA" alt="FEA0F1F6FEDE90BD0A925B4194DEAC11" height="200">` that doesn't seem to have any image format