# Scrapy passing a python list into item loader

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract a list of image urls and store it in a list format using scrapy item loaders

I am able to get image urls in list format using extract method but it's only storing one image.

code:

```py
def parseVictimData(self, response):
    victimItem = ItemLoader(item=CaimItem(), selector=response)
    victimItem.add_value('listing_url', response.meta['listing_url'])
    Images = response.xpath('//figure[contains(@data-fancybox,"gallery")]/@href').extract()
    victimItem.add_value('victim_image_url', Images)
    victimItem.add_xpath('listing_title', '//[@id="weldioo"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/h1')
```

Desired output:

`'image_urls': ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg']`

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Images in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523841/extracting-images-in-scrapy)

Comment: No, but I found the solution using Map Compose and my output processor had TakeFirst() method so I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one using MapConpose

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    def parseVictimData(self, response):
        victimItem = ItemLoader(item=CaimItem(), selector=response)
        victimItem.add_value('listing_url', response.meta['listing_url'])
        victimItem.add_xpath('listing_title', '//[@id="weldioo"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/h1')
        Images = response.xpath('//figure[contains(@data-fancybox,"gallery")]/@href')
        victimItem.add_xpath('victim_image_url', '//figure[contains(@data-fancybox,"gallery")]/@href', MapCompose(str.strip))
        yield victimItem.load_item()
```

Comment: Are you able to point out the issue in OP's code while you propose a solution?